# Email template variable missing when overriding observer of core module

Tags: magento-enterprise, event-observer, overrides

Hello all i want to do some changes in Magento Enterprise's Gift card functionality so that i have override the observer of **Enterprise_Giftcard** module into my local module **Essentiel_Giftcards** and its working correctly.

Here is my code

**Config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Essentiel_Giftcards>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Essentiel_Giftcards>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <essentiel_giftcards>
                <class>Essentiel_Giftcards_Model</class>
            </essentiel_giftcards>
            <essentiel_giftcard_resource>
                <class>Essentiel_Giftcards_Model_Resource</class>
            </essentiel_giftcard_resource>
            <enterprise_giftcard>
                <rewrite>
                    <observer>Essentiel_Giftcards_Model_Observer</observer>
                </rewrite>
            </enterprise_giftcard>
        </models>
     </global>
</config>
```

---

**Observer.php**

```
class Essentiel_Giftcards_Model_Observer extends Enterprise_GiftCard_Model_Observer
{
 /**
 * Generate gift card accounts after order save
 *
 * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
 * @return Enterprise_GiftCard_Model_Observer
 */
public function generateGiftCardAccounts(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    // sales_order_save_after

    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $requiredStatus = Mage::getStoreConfig(
        Enterprise_GiftCard_Model_Giftcard::XML_PATH_ORDER_ITEM_STATUS,
        $order->getStore());
    $loadedInvoices = array();

    foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
        if ($item->getProductType() == Enterprise_GiftCard_Model_Catalog_Product_Type_Giftcard::TYPE_GIFTCARD) {
            $qty = 0;
            $options = $item->getProductOptions();

            switch ($requiredStatus) {
                case Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item::STATUS_INVOICED:
                    $paidInvoiceItems = (isset($options['giftcard_paid_invoice_items'])
                        ? $options['giftcard_paid_invoice_items']
                        : array());
                    // find invoice for this order item
                    $invoiceItemCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_invoice_item_collection')
                        ->addFieldToFilter('order_item_id', $item->getId());

                    foreach ($invoiceItemCollection as $invoiceItem) {
                        $invoiceId = $invoiceItem->getParentId();
                        if(isset($loadedInvoices[$invoiceId])) {
                            $invoice = $loadedInvoices[$invoiceId];
                        } else {
                            $invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')
                                ->load($invoiceId);
                            $loadedInvoices[$invoiceId] = $invoice;
                        }
                        // check, if this order item has been paid
                        if ($invoice->getState() == Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::STATE_PAID &&
                            !in_array($invoiceItem->getId(), $paidInvoiceItems)
                        ) {
                                $qty += $invoiceItem->getQty();
                                $paidInvoiceItems[] = $invoiceItem->getId();
                        }
                    }
                    $options['giftcard_paid_invoice_items'] = $paidInvoiceItems;
                    break;
                default:
                    $qty = $item->getQtyOrdered();
                    if (isset($options['giftcard_created_codes'])) {
                        $qty -= count($options['giftcard_created_codes']);
                    }
                    break;
            }

            $hasFailedCodes = false;
            if ($qty > 0) {
                $isRedeemable = 0;
                if ($option = $item->getProductOptionByCode('giftcard_is_redeemable')) {
                    $isRedeemable = $option;
                }

                $lifetime = 0;
                if ($option = $item->getProductOptionByCode('giftcard_lifetime')) {
                    $lifetime = $option;
                }

                $amount = $item->getBasePrice();
                $websiteId = Mage::app()->getStore($order->getStoreId())->getWebsiteId();

                $data = new Varien_Object();
                $data->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
                    ->setAmount($amount)
                    ->setLifetime($lifetime)
                    ->setIsRedeemable($isRedeemable)
                    ->setOrderItem($item);

                $codes = (isset($options['giftcard_created_codes']) ?
                    $options['giftcard_created_codes'] : array());
                $goodCodes = 0;
                for ($i = 0; $i < $qty; $i++) {
                    try {
                        $code = new Varien_Object();
                        Mage::dispatchEvent('enterprise_giftcardaccount_create',
                            array('request'=>$data, 'code'=>$code));
                        $codes[] = $code->getCode();
                        $goodCodes++;
                    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                        $hasFailedCodes = true;
                        $codes[] = null;
                    }
                }
                if ($goodCodes && $item->getProductOptionByCode('giftcard_recipient_email')) {
                    $sender = $item->getProductOptionByCode('giftcard_sender_name');
                    $senderName = $item->getProductOptionByCode('giftcard_sender_name');
                    if ($senderEmail = $item->getProductOptionByCode('giftcard_sender_email')) {
                        $sender = "$sender <$senderEmail>";
                    }

                    $codeList = Mage::helper('enterprise_giftcard')->getEmailGeneratedItemsBlock()
                        ->setCodes($codes)
                        ->setIsRedeemable($isRedeemable)
                        ->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore($order->getStoreId()));
                    $balance = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(
                        Mage::app()->getStore($order->getStoreId())
                        ->getBaseCurrencyCode())->toCurrency($amount);

                    $templateData = array(
                        'name'                   => $item->getProductOptionByCode('giftcard_recipient_name'),
                        'email'                  => $item->getProductOptionByCode('giftcard_recipient_email'),
                        'sender_name_with_email' => $sender,
                        'sender_name'            => $senderName,
                        'gift_message'           => $item->getProductOptionByCode('giftcard_message'),
                        'giftcards'              => $codeList->toHtml(),
                        'balance'                => $balance,
                        'is_multiple_codes'      => 1 < $goodCodes,
                        'store'                  => $order->getStore(),
                        'store_name'             => $order->getStore()->getName(),//@deprecated after 1.4.0.0-beta1
                        'is_redeemable'          => $isRedeemable,
                    );

                    $email = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
                        ->setDesignConfig(array('store' => $item->getOrder()->getStoreId()));
                    $email->sendTransactional(
                        $item->getProductOptionByCode('giftcard_email_template'),
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(
                            Enterprise_GiftCard_Model_Giftcard::XML_PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY,
                            $item->getOrder()->getStoreId()),
                        $item->getProductOptionByCode('giftcard_recipient_email'),
                        $item->getProductOptionByCode('giftcard_recipient_name'),
                        $templateData
                    );

                    if ($email->getSentSuccess()) {
                        $options['email_sent'] = 1;
                    }
                }
                $options['giftcard_created_codes'] = $codes;
                $item->setProductOptions($options);
                $item->save();
            }
            if ($hasFailedCodes) {
                $url = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->getUrl('adminhtml/giftcardaccount');
                $message = Mage::helper('enterprise_giftcard')->__('Some of Gift Card Accounts were not generated properly. You can create Gift Card Accounts manually <a href="%s">here</a>.', $url);

                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($message);
            }
        }
    }

    return $this;
}

}
```

Well i am not doing any changes in above function i have just copied it from **Enterprise/GiftCard/Model/Observer.php** for further changes. Now when i process a giftcard order, every thing is working correct except the giftcard email which i am receiving just after generating the invoice from admin (completing order processing). Gift card email contain all the information except **Giftcard code**.

I wounder how the same function (without any change) is not working correctly after overriding it in a local module ?

Comment: Please post all your code either here, or in a github gist, I will download it and debug it =]

Comment: "Override" is a little vague here.  If you describe the technique you used to do this it may shed light on the problem.

Comment: @JeffreyL.Roberts : I have updated the code here.

Comment: @AlanStorm : I am great fan of you. I love your blog. I have updated the overall code i hope this may shade some light.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to receive the gift card numbers after I generated the invoice...

Make sure in the settings that

- Your gift card product has been created
- That your gift card product is enabled
- Your inventory quantity for your gift card is > 0
- That you have generated your giftcard code pool

Also, Make sure you have similar code to the following

app/etc/modules/JLR_Giftcarder.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <JLR_Giftcarder>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </JLR_Giftcarder>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/JLR/Giftcard/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <JLR_Giftcarder>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </JLR_Giftcarder>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <jlr_giftcarder>
                <class>JLR_Giftcarder_Model</class>
            </jlr_giftcarder>
            <enterprise_giftcard>
                <rewrite>
                    <observer>JLR_Giftcarder_Model_Observer</observer>
                </rewrite>
            </enterprise_giftcard>
        </models>
     </global>
</config>
```

app/code/local/JLR/Giftcarder/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php

class JLR_Giftcarder_Model_Observer extends Enterprise_GiftCard_Model_Observer
{
 /**
 * Generate gift card accounts after order save
 *
 * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
 * @return Enterprise_GiftCard_Model_Observer
 */
public function generateGiftCardAccounts(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    // sales_order_save_after

    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $requiredStatus = Mage::getStoreConfig(
        Enterprise_GiftCard_Model_Giftcard::XML_PATH_ORDER_ITEM_STATUS,
        $order->getStore());
    $loadedInvoices = array();

    foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
        if ($item->getProductType() == Enterprise_GiftCard_Model_Catalog_Product_Type_Giftcard::TYPE_GIFTCARD) {
            $qty = 0;
            $options = $item->getProductOptions();

            switch ($requiredStatus) {
                case Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item::STATUS_INVOICED:
                    $paidInvoiceItems = (isset($options['giftcard_paid_invoice_items'])
                        ? $options['giftcard_paid_invoice_items']
                        : array());
                    // find invoice for this order item
                    $invoiceItemCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_invoice_item_collection')
                        ->addFieldToFilter('order_item_id', $item->getId());

                    foreach ($invoiceItemCollection as $invoiceItem) {
                        $invoiceId = $invoiceItem->getParentId();
                        if (isset($loadedInvoices[$invoiceId])) {
                            $invoice = $loadedInvoices[$invoiceId];
                        } else {
                            $invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')
                                ->load($invoiceId);
                            $loadedInvoices[$invoiceId] = $invoice;
                        }
                        // check, if this order item has been paid
                        if ($invoice->getState() == Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::STATE_PAID &&
                            !in_array($invoiceItem->getId(), $paidInvoiceItems)
                        ) {
                                $qty += $invoiceItem->getQty();
                                $paidInvoiceItems[] = $invoiceItem->getId();
                        }
                    }
                    $options['giftcard_paid_invoice_items'] = $paidInvoiceItems;
                    break;
                default:
                    $qty = $item->getQtyOrdered();
                    if (isset($options['giftcard_created_codes'])) {
                        $qty -= count($options['giftcard_created_codes']);
                    }
                    break;
            }

            $hasFailedCodes = false;
            if ($qty > 0) {
                $isRedeemable = 0;
                if ($option = $item->getProductOptionByCode('giftcard_is_redeemable')) {
                    $isRedeemable = $option;
                }

                $lifetime = 0;
                if ($option = $item->getProductOptionByCode('giftcard_lifetime')) {
                    $lifetime = $option;
                }

                $amount = $item->getBasePrice();
                $websiteId = Mage::app()->getStore($order->getStoreId())->getWebsiteId();

                $data = new Varien_Object();
                $data->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
                    ->setAmount($amount)
                    ->setLifetime($lifetime)
                    ->setIsRedeemable($isRedeemable)
                    ->setOrderItem($item);

                $codes = (isset($options['giftcard_created_codes']) ?
                    $options['giftcard_created_codes'] : array());
                $goodCodes = 0;
                for ($i = 0; $i < $qty; $i++) {
                    try {
                        $code = new Varien_Object();
                        Mage::dispatchEvent('enterprise_giftcardaccount_create',
                            array('request'=>$data, 'code'=>$code));
                        $codes[] = $code->getCode();
                        $goodCodes++;
                    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                        $hasFailedCodes = true;
                        $codes[] = null;
                    }
                }
                if ($goodCodes && $item->getProductOptionByCode('giftcard_recipient_email')) {
                    $sender = $item->getProductOptionByCode('giftcard_sender_name');
                    $senderName = $item->getProductOptionByCode('giftcard_sender_name');
                    if ($senderEmail = $item->getProductOptionByCode('giftcard_sender_email')) {
                        $sender = "$sender <$senderEmail>";
                    }

                    $codeList = Mage::helper('enterprise_giftcard')->getEmailGeneratedItemsBlock()
                        ->setCodes($codes)
                        ->setIsRedeemable($isRedeemable)
                        ->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore($order->getStoreId()));
                    $balance = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(
                        Mage::app()->getStore($order->getStoreId())
                        ->getBaseCurrencyCode())->toCurrency($amount);

                    $templateData = array(
                        'name'                   => $item->getProductOptionByCode('giftcard_recipient_name'),
                        'email'                  => $item->getProductOptionByCode('giftcard_recipient_email'),
                        'sender_name_with_email' => $sender,
                        'sender_name'            => $senderName,
                        'gift_message'           => $item->getProductOptionByCode('giftcard_message'),
                        'giftcards'              => $codeList->toHtml(),
                        'balance'                => $balance,
                        'is_multiple_codes'      => 1 < $goodCodes,
                        'store'                  => $order->getStore(),
                        'store_name'             => $order->getStore()->getName(),//@deprecated after 1.4.0.0-beta1
                        'is_redeemable'          => $isRedeemable,
                    );

                    $email = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
                        ->setDesignConfig(array('store' => $item->getOrder()->getStoreId()));
                    $email->sendTransactional(
                        $item->getProductOptionByCode('giftcard_email_template'),
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(
                            Enterprise_GiftCard_Model_Giftcard::XML_PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY,
                            $item->getOrder()->getStoreId()),
                        $item->getProductOptionByCode('giftcard_recipient_email'),
                        $item->getProductOptionByCode('giftcard_recipient_name'),
                        $templateData
                    );

                    if ($email->getSentSuccess()) {
                        $options['email_sent'] = 1;
                    }
                }
                $options['giftcard_created_codes'] = $codes;
                $item->setProductOptions($options);
                $item->save();
            }
            if ($hasFailedCodes) {
                $url = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->getUrl('adminhtml/giftcardaccount');
                $message = Mage::helper('enterprise_giftcard')->__('Some of Gift Card Accounts were not generated properly. You can create Gift Card Accounts manually <a href="%s">here</a>.', $url);

                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($message);
            }
        }
    }

    return $this;
}

}
```